# Put message.author.id into multiple arrays based on numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This might be a long shot.... I have a code that puts the message.author.id inside of an array in a JSON file.

Which looks like this

```
    if(message.content.startsWith (prefix + " craft")) {
        let editedmessage = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 1);
        let skill = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(9);

        if(!client.msgs[skill]) return message.reply("I cant find that skill"); {
            client.msgs[skill] = [message.author.id]
        }
            if(!client.msgs[skill].includes(message.author.id)) client.msgs[skill].push(message.author.id);
            {

            message.reply("You can now " + editedmessage)
        }
    }
```

If the command written on discord was ex. "!v craft T5 Bow" it would put the id in like this

```
 "T5 Bow": [
        "95790380057894912"
    ],
```

Here is why my problem comes in. The T5 Bow also exists as T4 Bow, T6 Bow, T7 Bow and T8 Bow.
Is there a way to sort all members that uses the command under multiple arrays.
The T stands for Tier, so a T5 Bow is a Tier 5 Bow.
But if you could craft Tier 5 Bow, you can also craft Tier 4 Bow.

So for example. If a User writes "!v craft T6 Bow" they should be put in "T4 Bow", "T5 Bow" and "T6 Bow"

Is this possible?

This is what my JSON file looks like

```
{
    "T4 Plate Boots": [],
    "T4 Plate Armor": [],
    "T4 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T4 Sword": [],
    "T4 Battleaxe": [],
    "T4 Mace": [],
    "T4 Hammer": [],
    "T4 Crossbow": [],
    "T4 Shield": [],
    "T4 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T4 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T4 Leather Hood": [],
    "T4 Bow": [],
    "T4 Spear": [],
    "T4 Nature Staff": [],
    "T4 Dagger": [],
    "T4 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T4 Torch": [],
    "T4 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T4 Bag": [],
    "T4 Cape": [],
    "T4 Fisherman": [],
    "T4 Lumberjack": [],
    "T4 Quarrier": [],
    "T4 Miner": [],
    "T4 Skinner": [],
    "T4 Harvester": [],
    "T5 Plate Boots": [],
    "T5 Plate Armor": [],
    "T5 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T5 Sword": [],
    "T5 Battleaxe": [],
    "T5 Mace": [],
    "T5 Hammer": [],
    "T5 Crossbow": [],
    "T5 Shield": [],
    "T5 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T5 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T5 Leather Hood": [],
    "T5 Bow": [
        "95790380057894912"
    ],
    "T5 Spear": [],
    "T5 Nature Staff": [],
    "T5 Dagger": [],
    "T5 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T5 Torch": [],
    "T5 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T5 Bag": [],
    "T5 Cape": [],
    "T5 Fisherman": [],
    "T5 Lumberjack": [],
    "T5 Quarrier": [],
    "T5 Miner": [],
    "T5 Skinner": [],
    "T5 Harvester": [],
    "T6 Plate Boots": [],
    "T6 Plate Armor": [],
    "T6 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T6 Sword": [],
    "T6 Battleaxe": [],
    "T6 Mace": [],
    "T6 Hammer": [],
    "T6 Crossbow": [],
    "T6 Shield": [],
    "T6 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T6 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T6 Leather Hood": [],
    "T6 Bow": [],
    "T6 Spear": [],
    "T6 Nature Staff": [],
    "T6 Dagger": [],
    "T6 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T6 Torch": [],
    "T6 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T6 Bag": [],
    "T6 Cape": [],
    "T6 Fisherman": [],
    "T6 Lumberjack": [],
    "T6 Quarrier": [],
    "T6 Miner": [],
    "T6 Skinner": [],
    "T6 Harvester": [],
    "T7 Plate Boots": [],
    "T7 Plate Armor": [],
    "T7 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T7 Sword": [],
    "T7 Battleaxe": [],
    "T7 Mace": [],
    "T7 Hammer": [],
    "T7 Crossbow": [],
    "T7 Shield": [],
    "T7 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T7 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T7 Leather Hood": [],
    "T7 Bow": [
        "95790380057894912"
    ],
    "T7 Spear": [],
    "T7 Nature Staff": [],
    "T7 Dagger": [],
    "T7 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T7 Torch": [],
    "T7 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T7 Bag": [],
    "T7 Cape": [],
    "T7 Fisherman": [],
    "T7 Lumberjack": [],
    "T7 Quarrier": [],
    "T7 Miner": [],
    "T7 Skinner": [],
    "T7 Harvester": [],
    "T8 Plate Boots": [],
    "T8 Plate Armor": [],
    "T8 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T8 Sword": [],
    "T8 Battleaxe": [],
    "T8 Mace": [],
    "T8 Hammer": [],
    "T8 Crossbow": [],
    "T8 Shield": [],
    "T8 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T8 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T8 Leather Hood": [],
    "T8 Bow": [
        "95790380057894912"
    ],
    "T8 Spear": [],
    "T8 Nature Staff": [],
    "T8 Dagger": [],
    "T8 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T8 Torch": [],
    "T8 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T8 Bag": [],
    "T8 Cape": [],
    "T8 Fisherman": [],
    "T8 Lumberjack": [],
    "T8 Quarrier": [],
    "T8 Miner": [],
    "T8 Skinner": [],
    "T8 Harvester": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an object based data structure.  You can order it based on item type with tier sorted below that.

```
{
   "PlateBoots": {
      "T4": [],
      "T5": []
      // etc
    },
}
```

Once you have parsed your JSON you access these in object notation:

```js
let tier4PlateBoots = myJson.PlateBoots.T4;
```

You can then use a loop to go through all of them.

```js
for(let boots in myJson.PlateBoots)
{ // Loops through each tier
   for(let player of boots)
   {
       // Loops through each person
   }
}
```

Comment: How would my code here 
´
if(message.content.startsWith (prefix + " craft")) {
        let editedmessage = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 1);
        let skill = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(9);

        if(!client.msgs[skill]) return message.reply("I cant find that skill"); {
            client.msgs[skill] = [message.author.id]
        }
            if(!client.msgs[skill].includes(message.author.id)) client.msgs[skill].push(message.author.id);
            {

            message.reply("You can now " + editedmessage)
        }
    }
´ 
look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
//load your json here
let data = {}
//user message
let message = "T8 Leather Hood";
//getting the tier type
let tierType = message.substr(2);
//getting the tier number in the message
let tierNumberMsg = message.split("")[1]

for(let k in data)
{
//getting the current tier number
  let tierNumber = k.split(" ")[0].split("")[1]
  if(tierNumber<=tierNumberMsg && k.includes(tierType))
    data[k].push("userId")
}
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Where should I put it in my code? Sorry for being a noob

Comment: @RasmusHornung within the conditional that checks whether there is a command or not. In your case is `if(message.content.startsWith (prefix + " craft"))`

Comment: in my code, the variable `message` is the same as the `skill` in your case